# redis store map within map as value

Tags: redis

The map I want to store in Redis is

```
KEY -> KEY1(string) VALUE1(string)
       KEY2(string) VALUE2(map)
```

In an operation with this structure, I want to add key/value to VALUE2 without first retrieving VALUE2. Is it possible ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to save the roundtrip time to query VALUE2. You can write a lua script which will get and set value2 at redis server end.

Comment: Yes. So it cannot be done with a client?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature shipped with Redis.